# How to highlight selected location on amCharts

Tags: javascript, amcharts, ammap

I am using amCharts. On hover of the location and on click of the particular location I am able to highlight the area.

```
rollOverOutlineColor: "#000000",
rollOverColor: "#62B4EB",
selectedColor: "#0078c8",
```

But clicking on the next location, current one will highlight and the old one will loose. I want to show all selected /clicked location to be highlighted on a particular color.

```
map = new AmCharts.AmMap();
map.areasSettings = {
    autoZoom: false,
    rollOverOutlineColor: "#000000",
    rollOverColor: "#62B4EB",
    selectedColor: "#0078c8",
    color: "#999999",
    selectable:true
};

map.pathToImages = '/images/';

map.dataProvider = data;
```

[image]

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution comes in the form of using area's [`showAsSelected`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptmaps/MapArea#showAsSelected) property.

When click event ([`clickMapObject`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptmaps/AmMap#events)) occurs, you can set `showAsSelected` property of clicked area to keep it selected.

```
map.addListener("clickMapObject", function(event) {
  event.mapObject.showAsSelected = true;
});
```

Please note that `showAsSelected` was introduced in some later 3.x version. (I'm sorry I can't quite recall which one) If you are using old version of JavaScript Maps, it might not work.

Here's a working demo with the current version:

```js
var map;
var data = {
  "map": "worldLow",
  "getAreasFromMap": true
};

map = new AmCharts.AmMap();
map.areasSettings = {
  autoZoom: false,
  rollOverOutlineColor: "#000000",
  rollOverColor: "#62B4EB",
  selectedColor: "#0078c8",
  color: "#999999",
  selectable: true
};

map.pathToImages = '/images/';

map.dataProvider = data;

map.addListener("clickMapObject", function(event) {
  event.mapObject.showAsSelected = true;
});

map.write("chartdiv");
```

```html
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/ammap.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/maps/js/worldLow.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>
```

---

UPDATE: In case you want to toggle whole groups of countries using their `groupId` parameter, here's how this could be done:

```
map.addListener("clickMapObject", function(event) {
  if (event.mapObject.groupId !== undefined) {
    for(var i = 0; i < map.dataProvider.areas.length; i++) {
      var area = map.dataProvider.areas[i];
      if (area.groupId == event.mapObject.groupId) {
        area.showAsSelected = true;
      }
    }
    map.validateData();
  }
  else {
    event.mapObject.showAsSelected = true;
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks ,it is working for my state and country location.Do you have any idea how can I implement for entire regions like cocom.For example i can select entire Asia or Africa.

Comment: Well, you would need to cycle through all of the African countries and set `showAsSelected` for all of them. Are you using `groupId` parameters to group them?

Comment: I'll update my answer to accommodate for this scenario.